# How typeahead search should be done in vespa?

Tags: vespa

I'm trying to build typeahead search using vespa. Since there is a lot of data, I don't want to use streaming mode. Wildcard search is something which I was expecting to see, but it looks restricted to streaming mode(Regular expressions and match:substring are applicable only for streaming mode). Any pointers on how to achieve it or customization will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've seen applications do for this is as follows:

1. Put all the text in an attribute array AND set fast-search on that array. That gives you consistent very low latency as you only access memory, and ability to use prefix matching. It disables full text relevance but you don't need that for this.
2. Use prefix matching, not substring. If you want to match all terms by prefix, you can just set match: prefix on the field in the search definition. It may give a better user experience to only do prefix matching of the last term though. In that case keep default matching and rewrite the query (in a Searcher) to make the last WordItem and PrefixItem instead.

E.g you can define the field in the search definition like this:

```
field suggestions type array<string> {
    indexing: input myinputtextfield |split "\\s+" | summary | attribute
    attribute: fast-search
}
```

And to do prefix matching on the last term, add a [Searcher component](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/searcher-development.html) which does something like this:

```
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.CompositeItem;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.Item;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.PrefixItem;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.WordItem;
import com.yahoo.search.Query;
import com.yahoo.search.Result;
import com.yahoo.search.Searcher;
import com.yahoo.search.query.QueryTree;
import com.yahoo.search.searchchain.Execution;

import java.util.ListIterator;

public class PrefixMatchSearcher extends Searcher {

    @Override
    public Result search(Query query, Execution execution) {
        matchLastByPrefix(query);
        return execution.search(query);
    }

    private boolean matchLastByPrefix(Query query) {
        boolean spaceTerminated = query.getModel().getQueryString().endsWith(" ");
        if (spaceTerminated) return false;

        QueryTree tree = query.getModel().getQueryTree();
        if (tree.getRoot() instanceof WordItem) {
            tree.setRoot(toPrefixItem((WordItem) tree.getRoot()));
            return true;
        }
        else if (tree.getRoot() instanceof CompositeItem) {
            CompositeItem root = (CompositeItem) tree.getRoot();
            for (ListIterator<Item> i = root.getItemIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Item child = i.next();
                if (i.hasNext()) continue; // Skip to last

                if (child instanceof WordItem) { 
                    i.set(toPrefixItem((WordItem)child));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private PrefixItem toPrefixItem(WordItem word) {
        return new PrefixItem(word.getWord(), word.getIndexName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. Did you mean to add all the values to a string array in a single document and query it? I might need this feature for an e-commerce application with millions of products.

Comment: No, each document is suggestion/product stored in myinputtextfield, e.g "my super duper product" which gets transformed into array form.

Comment: For best performance/low latency for type-ahead queries you also should consider making a simple explicit document summary which references your in-memory attribute fields https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-summaries.html